# What are the reasons to have an apache webserver fronting Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2

I have already distributed the static content, so I do not need Apache to do that, also URL rewriting is handled by a tomcat filter. is there any other reason to have Apache in front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxying and load-balancing?

Being a more mature, and native project, Apache httpd often gives better performance and stability than using Tomcat directly.